# How long can a Game Centre Achievements title or description be before causing problems?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, game-center

Are there any restrictions on the length of the title or descriptions of Game Center achievements?

I don't just mean what you're allowed to enter. I also mean any truncations or size-reductions on any built-in screens that will make it look awful to the user if it's longer than a particular length.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a limit set by ITunes Connect, and of course it will depend on the particular text you have, since the font is not monospaced, but from my own practical experience I get the following rough estimations:

Inside your App (if you are using the custom `ModalViewControllers`): Title 20 chars, Description 80 chars

In the Game Center App: Title 14 chars, Description 65 chars

So if you want them to always fit you should check them on the Game Center App on all the devices and localizations you plan to make your app available in.